# How can I intercept syscall libc function in C++ without writing any code in C file

Tags: c++, c, libc

How can intercept libc function in C++ using LD_PRELOAD. I want to write code only in C++ file and all the logic of symbol fishing (dlsym) must be in C++ file.
Please give an example.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. How about using `extern "C"`? This effectively lets you write C functions in C++ by assigning C linkage.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to intercept only *library* calls, you can insert your hooks in the `GOT` of the executable or at the dynamic loader resolver pointer (`GOT[2]`). I don't have sample code at hand, but [this aricle](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/) is good for background.

If you want to intercept all *syscalls* (including those in the binary itself, e.g. if it's linked statically), you can use `ptrace (PTRACE_SYSCALL)` to be notified of all syscalls happening in the process. There are [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759598/ptracing-syscalls) on StackOverflow but they usually assume you're tracing another process. If you want to trace the same process you're in, you can use the `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME)` call.